# SharePoint 2010: How to display an external list as a calendar?

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-2010, bcs

In SharePoint 2010 BCS, I have created an external content type to retrieve a list of appointments from our LoB application. This works, and I can see the list of appointments in SharePoint.

The problem is, I can *only* see the appointments as a list. I want to display them in a calendar, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

I've set the Office Item Type to Appointment, and everything I've read seems to imply that I can synchronize this list with an Outlook calendar, but I can't find any option to display the list as a calendar in SharePoint itself.

Has anyone found a way to display an external list in a calendar, or am I stuck with writing my own or buying a third-party add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot use the calendar view with an external list. Here is a solution using a custom web part
https://web.archive.org/web/20110313155828/http://www.tonstegeman.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=60

Comment: Any success since than?